# YouCompleteMe installation-problem with Vim, Vundle on macOS 10.4.6/hombrew

Tags: macvim, plugin-you-complete-me, macos, original-vim

I tried to install YCM. After some faults, Vundle shows that the install is complete, but YCM-Server is down. When I ran `install.py` I allways get this kind of error

```
...
' fatal error:
      'filesystem' file not found
#include <filesystem>'
...
```

Before I updated all dependencies and libraries with

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

The complete messages are

```
...
Searching Python 3.9 libraries...
Found Python library: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin/libpython3.9.dylib
Found Python headers folder: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin/libpython3.9.dylib (found suitable version "3.9.1", minimum required is "3.6")
CMake Deprecation Warning at ycm/CMakeLists.txt:18 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- NOT using libclang, no semantic completion for C/C++/ObjC will be available
CMake Warning at ycm/CMakeLists.txt:343 (message):
  Unknown compiler - not passing -lstdc++fs


-- NOT using clang-tidy for static analysis.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /private/var/folders/5g/bx1143b952g7j_22vx4s7j000000gn/T/ycm_build_92gg74k5
Scanning dependencies of target ycm_core
[ 31%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Character.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CharacterRepository.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CodePoint.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Candidate.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CandidateRepository.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CodePointRepository.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierDatabase.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o
[ 56%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierUtils.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Result.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Utils.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/Utils.cpp:18:
/Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/Utils.h:23:10: fatal error:
      'filesystem' file not found
#include <filesystem>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/Result.cpp:19:
/Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/Utils.h:23:10: fatal error:
      'filesystem' file not found
#include <filesystem>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Result.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/CodePointRepository.cpp:20:
/Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/Utils.h:23:10: fatal error:
      'filesystem' file not found
#include <filesystem>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/CharacterRepository.cpp:19:
/Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/Utils.h:23:10: fatal error:
      'filesystem' file not found
#include <filesystem>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CodePointRepository.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CharacterRepository.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/CandidateRepository.cpp:19:
/Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/Utils.h:23:10: fatal error:
      'filesystem' file not found
#include <filesystem>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CandidateRepository.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/IdentifierUtils.cpp:18:
/Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/IdentifierUtils.h:23:10: fatal error:
      'filesystem' file not found
#include <filesystem>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/IdentifierCompleter.cpp:21:
/Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/IdentifierUtils.h:23:10: fatal error:
      'filesystem' file not found
#include <filesystem>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
In file included from /Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/IdentifierDatabase.cpp:22:
/Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/IdentifierUtils.h:23:10: fatal error:
      'filesystem' file not found
#include <filesystem>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierUtils.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Utils.cpp.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierDatabase.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/PythonSupport.cpp:22:
/Users/username/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/Utils.h:23:10: **fatal error:
      'filesystem' file not found
#include <filesystem>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~**
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [ycm_core] Error 2
ERROR: the build failed.

NOTE: it is *highly* unlikely that this is a bug but rather
that this is a problem with the configuration of your system
or a missing dependency. Please carefully read CONTRIBUTING.md
and if you're sure that it is a bug, please raise an issue on the
issue tracker, including the entire output of this script
and the invocation line used to run it.
...
```

What is the problem, and what is the solution?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I've cleaned up your post a bit (please avoid even masked versions of rude or foul language; you may want to check out our [Code of Conduct](https://vi.stackexchange.com/conduct)). You may also want to check in with the YCM developers—they or their github might have relevant discussions.

Comment: E.g., https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues/3813, https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues/3805